# Get intersection between two List, which can contain an object multiple times

Tags: dart

I have to Lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5];
list2 = [3,4,5];
```

I want to get the intersection:

```
A = [1,2,3,3,4,5]
```

The condition is: ALL_ELEMENTS_OFF_A+ ALL_ELEMENTS_OFF_LIST2 = ALL_ELLEMENTS_OF_LIST1 ; list1>list2

Thanks to everyone who can help.

Comment: `list2.forEach(list1.remove);`

Comment: this do not return the intersection of list1∩list2

Comment: Your question asks for difference not intersection.

Comment: Thanks i have just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the intersection of: List1∩List2

```
  while(list2.isNotEmpty){
          for (int i = 0; i < list1.length;) {
        if (list2.last== list1[i]) {
          list2.removeLast();
          list1.removeAt(i);
          break;
        } else {
          i++;
        }
      }
  }
```